# Grayscale double hover effect

Tags: html, css, hover, grayscale

I'm trying to make a effect for the social media of my website. All the social icons are inside a  and the div has a hover effect `filter: grayscale(100%)`. What I want to do is reset the filter to `filter: grayscale(0%)` on the social icon I'm hovering (give color to it again). I tried a lot of things but it seems to be bug or at least for webkit.

```css
.social:hover :not(h3) {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.social img {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

.facebook img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(%);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <h3>Stay connected!</h3>
  <a target="_blank" class="btn facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/LaDulceriaCuracao/"><img src="../Media/SocialMedia/facebook.gif"></a>
  <a target="_blank" class="instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/dulceriacuracao/"><img src="../Media/SocialMedia/instagram.gif" /></a>
  <a target="_blank" class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/La_Dulceria1"><img src="../Media/SocialMedia/twitter.gif" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I knew I had not explained well. What I want is that by passing with the cursor over the Social Media( Class="social") container all the icons to turn gray except the one that is exactly at the cursor. I don't know how to explain it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/omdq64n5/

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  flex: 1;
}
i {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: red;
}
.container:hover i {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.item:hover i {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></div>
  <div class="item"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></div>
  <div class="item"><i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, something like that! Can you help me doing this with the <a> and <img> tag? It will help me alot

Comment: It was pretty easy, just had to adapt my example to your code. https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/omdq64n5/1/ I removed the div's wrapping the a tags, they weren't needed, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Also, take note of the !important I added to the a:hover

Comment: You're welcome. For further information read up on [CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) when you can, it can get real tricky at times.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just remove the whole declaration?

`.social:hover :not(h3){ filter: grayscale(100%); opacity: 0.8; -webkit-transition : all 300ms linear; }`

You can also comment it out with 
`/* code to remove here */`

Comment: I knew I had not explained well. What I want is that by passing with the cursor over the Social Media( Class="social") container all the icons to turn gray except the one that is exactly at the cursor. I don't know how to explain it..

Comment: How instead of `.facebook img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(%);
  opacity: 1;
}` use `.facebook a:hover {
  filter: grayscale(%);
  opacity: 1;
}`

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work, It seems to be a webkit bug because I opened my site with explorer and the filter reset work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove filter line code from social hover class like this :

```
.

social:hover :not(h3){
/*filter: grayscale(100%);*/
opacity: 0.8;
-webkit-transition : all 300ms linear;

}
```

Comment: I knew I had not explained well. What I want is that by passing with the cursor over the Social Media( Class="social") container all the icons to turn gray except the one that is exactly at the cursor. I don't know how to explain it..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```css
.social:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.social:hover > div {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.social:hover > div:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<section class="social">
  <h3>Stay connected!</h3>
  <div><a target="_blank" class="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/LaDulceriaCuracao/"><img src="../Media/SocialMedia/facebook.gif"></a></div>
  <div><a target="_blank" class="instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/dulceriacuracao/"><img src="../Media/SocialMedia/instagram.gif" /></a></div>
  <div><a target="_blank" class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/La_Dulceria1"><img src="../Media/SocialMedia/twitter.gif" /></a></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the effect I want but with grayscale